# Rails order by associated data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

Is it possible to order the results of school.classrooms by the teacher's name?  I want to do this directly in the association, and not a separate call.

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :classrooms
end


class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  belongs_to :teacher
end


class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :classroom
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work if you are using rails 3.x

```
school.classrooms.includes(:teacher).order("teachers.name")
```

Comment: +1 note - this answer was not done 'in the association'... but I think that is a good thing ! because actually doing it there is just wrong.  Doing it *using* the association as shown in this example is the correct form.