# Rails Order by Contained Objects 2 Levels Deep?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I include ordering in an 'order' ActiveRelation call that's more than one level deep?

That is, I understand the answer when it's only one level deep (asked and answered at [Rails order by associated data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875184/rails-order-by-associated-data)).  However, I have a case where the data on which I want to sort is two levels deep.

Specifically, in my schema a SongbookEntry contains a Recording, which contains an Artist and a Song.  I want to be able to sort SongbookEntry lists by song title.

I can go one level deep and sort Recordings by song title:

```
@recordings = Recording.includes(:song).order('songs.title')
```

...but don't know how to go two levels deep.  In addition, it would be great if I could sort on the recording (that is, the song title and the artist name) -- is this possible without descending into SQL?

Thanks for any help,

Keith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you model the association between `SongbookEntry` and `Song` as such:

```
class SongbookEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_one :song, through: :recording
end
```

you will be able to access `@songbookentry.song` and `SongbookEntry.joins(:song)` using your existing schema.

Edit:

Applying the same idea for `Artist`, a possible query would be:

```
SongbookEntry.joins(:song,:artist).order('songs.title','artists.name')
```

Note that this may not be the most efficient operation (multiple joins involved) even though it looks Rails-ish, so later on you may want to denormalize the tables as Ryan suggested, or find another way to model the data.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise storing the artist name (and possibly the song title too) on the recording itself, so you don't have to "descend into SQL".

Answer (score 0):

Try this
  SongbookEntry.includes(:recording=>[:artist,:song]).order('songs.title, artists.name')

You can use joins in place of includes if you don't want to use associated tables fields in views